# Indian Passport Renewal-exiting US

Tags: air-travel

I have recently renewed my Indian passport. Now i entered US with my old passport. My question is when i exit US, the airlines sent my details to US CBP so that they have the record of my entry/exit. I believe this is tracked using passport number. Since now i have a new passport with a new number, do i book ticket with my old passport or new passport. How will CBP track my departure if new passport number in used by airlines to book ticket?

THanks,
Samrat

Answer (score 10):

Book your flight with your new passport details. CBP is responsible for figuring out how to link them together (they will). You can verify this later using the online I94 query tool (https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/).

Comment: If your departure isn't correctly recorded (you probably should give it a week) it is possible to have the departure recorded. Unfortunately, the website isn't clear on how to do this.

Comment: Can confirm, my wife did this and her departure was recorded correctly.